# Cannot connect to Tor network

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, windows

When I double click on the `tor.exe`,  a window comes up saying "connecting to the Tor Network".  The status bar goes almost half way and stops.  I am using Windows 7 64 bit and NOT using any proxies. Where could be a problem?

Comment: i just had a similar issue. It seemed to have something to do with Firefox, (the non-tor version) being open and being in the middle of an update. I tried shutting down firefox and tor and restarting them on their own, and in combination until it worked all of a sudden.

Answer (score 1):

The Tor Browser Bundle has a start script which is called `Start Tor Browser` (maybe appended with `.exe`). It is in the directory where you unpacked the software. The `tor.exe` is probably in the `Tor/` subdirectory. So when you navigate one level up, you'll see the start script. Double-click on it. After a short waiting time the Tor Browser will pop up and you can use the software.

Comment: i think the problem is tor not connecting. Starting up fine, but not managing to get connected to network/ relay. I have the same problem. I turned off firewall for the app.